# Charge between grounded plates

Tags: electrostatics

A few days ago I saw in an article that if we place a positive charge $Q$ between 2 infinite ,parallel and grounded plates,  then the sum of the induced charges on the plates has to be equal to $-Q$. I don't know how I could prove this statement using Gauss's law. $ $   Any ideas?

Comment: There is no closed surface due to the connection to earth, so perhaps Gauss's law is not the way to go.

Comment: Please refer to the journal article [**here**](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243488821_Point_charge_between_two_parallel_grounded_planes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the plates are infinite, we won't be able to get a Gauss's surface around them, but, to find the answer to this question, we don't have to. If the distance between the plates is not infinite, we could make the Gauss's surface big enough to achieve any level of accuracy.

Since the potential of the plates is zero, there won't be any electric field on their external surfaces and no electric field around or inside the grounding wires (presumably, one wire for each plate). The field between the plates won't be zero, but, if the Gauss's surface is big enough, it could be made as small as we choose.

[image]

Therefore, the flux through the Gauss's surface could be made as close to zero as we choose. If so, according to the Gauss's law, the charge enclosed inside the surface should be zero as well and, since the known charge between the plates is $Q$, the charge induced into the plates must be $-Q$.

Obviously, these charge will be located on the inside surfaces of the plates.